# How to change Postgres timezone

Tags: sql, postgresql, timezone

I tried to load my data for column hour = 16 ( current time 16:32 ) but i got data for hour = 15. Why is PostGreSQL late ?

```
SELECT d.* 
FROM data_analyse d
JOIN competences_territoriales ct ON d.ogc_fid = ct.ogc_fid
WHERE ST_Within(
    ST_Centroid(ST_SetSRID(ct.wkb_geometry::geometry, 4326)), 
    (SELECT wkb_geometry FROM departements WHERE code = '33')
) AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC') = hour;
```

i tried also this command `AND EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW()) = hour;` no changes.

I tried to see my current sql timezone with `SELECT @@GLOBAL.time_zone AS global_time_zone, @@SESSION.time_zone AS session_time_zone;` but i get error missing FROM-clause entry for table "global" i know this error but dont know how to fix it here.

I use Postgre SQL 15.5

Comment: Is this a MySQL question or a PostgreSQL question?  I think it's the former, but the title says postgreSQL.

Comment: Oops i don't know why i wrote MySQL, this is a PostgreSQL question sorry !

Comment: Ok, but the @@ syntax is a MySQL thing, not a PostgreSQL thing.

Comment: Maybe instead of select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW() AT TIME ZONE 'UTC')
you want just 
select EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NOW() )

Comment: 1) Run `SHOW timezone` to get time zone.  2) You are seeing a difference because the datetime is being transformed  to `UTC` from the database timezone. If you want the `hour` in local time don't do the `AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'`.

Comment: The important question is: what is the data type of `hour`?

Comment: Ok @@ is a MySQL thing only thank you Kirke i didn't know.

Comment: i did SHOW timezone, so my sql base is in GMT, i will try to set it to UTC, thanks you Adrian

Comment: Hour is an integer Laurenz